# template template parameter scenario

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `MYVEC` which is passed as a second template param to another template class `FOO`

```
template<class T>
class MYVEC{ };

template<class T,class U>
class FOO { };

main()
{
       FOO<int, MYVEC<int>> obj;
}
```

If I could instantiate `FOO` in the above way, why then would i require template template parameter syntax ?

e.g. when will i need the following:

```
template<class T>
class MYVEC{ };

template<class T, template<typename> class C>  //or     template<class T, template<typename> class C=MYVEC>
class FOO { };
```

Also, my compiler doesn't throw any error when trying to instantiate it as :

```
    FOO<int, MYVEC> obj; //I wonder what is the second template param type  here
```

But this is a compiler error, though i expected this to work:

```
    FOO<int, MYVEC<int>> obj;
```

Comment: What version of C++ is this?

Comment: g++ compiler 4.8.3

Comment: You should update your compiler. That is really old at this point.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to pass a class to something wanting a class template? Why do you expect an error passing a template to something that wants a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template template parameters have a niche area where they are applicable.

Say you have a class managing some resource. Now, you can either store them in a vector, or a list or some exotic container you cooked up. **OR** you can entirely leave that choice up to your user by asking for a container type through template template parameter as part of your class definition.

Some code to illustrate the differences.

```
template<typename T> class MyResManagerv1
{
    std::vector<T> resources;
    // rest of your implementation details

    // rest of your public interface
};

MyResManagerv1<my_file_type> v1;

template<typename T> class MyResManagerv2
{
    std::list<T> resources;
    // rest of your implementation details

    // rest of your public interface
};

MyResManagerv2<my_file_type> v2;

template<typename T> class MyResManagerv3
{
    my_exotic_container<T> resources;
    // rest of your implementation details

    // rest of your public interface
};

MyResManagerv3<my_file_type> v3;

template<typename T, template<typename> class container> class MyResManagerv4
{
    container<T> resources;
    // rest of your implementation details

    // rest of your public interface
};

MyResManagerv4<my_file_type, std::vector> v4;
MyResManagerv4<my_file_type, std::list> v5;
MyResManagerv4<my_file_type, my_exotic_container> v6;
```

This final version *(which is C++17 only, can be tweaked to be compatible with C++11 and others)* can impersonate any of the other ones if you pass them a vector, list or your exotic container. As long as they conform to the interface your class expects.

Comment: Maybe should note that this only works for `c++17`. You're also still missing `class` for the three first versions.

Comment: Oops! My bad about missing class/struct. And could you elaborate why this would only work for C++17?

Comment: @super Are you referring to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)? "P must be at least as specialized as A (since C++17)"

Comment: I'm refering to the fact that both `std::vector` and `std::list` has 2 template parameters. The second argument has a default value, but prior to `c++17` this would fail to match with a template template argument with just one parameter.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NgeWvzamSpCRBKWF)

Comment: Enormous thanks! I have updated my answer to highlight this point. Thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204210/discussion-between-tanveer-badar-and-super).

Answer (score 2):

To cut to the cruft of the error, it is essentially telling you that `MYVEC<int>` is not a template type because the type has been fully realized. Whereas when you use `MYVEC`, this is a template type because it still expects a template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> If I could instantiate `FOO` in the above way, why then would i require template template parameter syntax ?

Because you can *prevent* `FOO` being instantiated in ways that are problematic, e.g.

```
main()
{
    FOO<int, MYVEC<std::string>> obj2; // Probably fails to compile with a cryptic message
    FOO<int, MYVEC<short>> obj3; // Hopefully fails to compile, could easily have undefined behaviour
}
```